# After redirecting, the iframe #document loads outside the iframe

Tags: iframe, ws-federation

Currently, my web page is loading an iframe which uses ws-federation to authenticate and then it redirects to wanted iframe web page.

The problem happens when it loads and certificates for the first time because, after bypassing the certificate, the iframe loads visually correctly the web page but his #document appears at parent's top-0 left-0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the solution.

When the Iframe was making the redirection, it was not being displayed (`display: none`) and when it finally loads the wanted web page (after the redirection), the display attribute was changed (`display: block`).

This was causing to the Iframe's #document to appears at top-0 left-0 (because display makes the element to not take space). So, just changed the display property to `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` and now it works perfect!.